# Storing multiple structs in continuous memory area in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, struct

I want to store a state variable composed of multiple POD-structs of various types into a single memory area. Since the combination of structs used to make up the state variable is decided at run time, i cannot just place them into a surrounding struct or class. Also i want the number of memory allocations to be as low as possible.
What is the best way to do it? Is the following code legal/portable or can it cause alignment errors on some platforms / with some compilers?

```
struct TestA {
    int a;
    short b;
};

struct TestB {
    int c;
    float d;
    char e;
};

int main() {
    void* mem = new uint8_t[sizeof(TestA) + sizeof(TestB)];
    TestA* a1 = (TestA*) mem;
    a1->a = a1->b = 42;
    a1++;
    TestB* b = (TestB*) a1;
    b->c = 5;
    b->d = 23.f;
    b->e = 'e';
}
```

Comment: That sounds a bit like a hack I'd do in C. If you're writing in c++, why not use polymorphism?  One base class and multiple derived classes, and/or a creational pattern to construct these at runtime would go a long way for portability and maintainability.

Comment: You make a valid point, and i have already considered such a design. However i figured the many memory allocations and indirections might prove to be a performance problem, since for my specific application i want to store the state of arbritarily combinable sound synthesis components which obviously have to be traversed 44100 times a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is essentially "placement new." So all caveats apply here too. If the memory location is not aligned properly for the given type, then you're into undefined behavior. In your code:

```
a1++;
```

is not guaranteed to give an address that's properly aligned for a `TestB`. So your code is not standard-conformant.

Comment: So i guess the only standard conformant way to do what i'm asking is to put all possible structs in an union and allocate an array of this union.

Comment: @BillAskaga It's gonna waste some memory, but I can't think of any other way either.